# Comparing String with Timepicker Android

Tags: java, android, time, android-timepicker

I have a time value in `String` format, e.g. `"2:00"`, and I want to compare it with the the time I have got from timepicker (24 hour format) in my activity. For example I want to check, if the time from timepicker is less than the `String` value. In simple words, I want to convert the `String` to 24 hour format and compare it with the timepicker time. I am unable to find any solution.

```
TimePicker st = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
st.setIs24HourView(true); 
String StartTime = "2:00";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert to 24 hour format

```
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date date = parseFormat.parse("10:30 PM");
System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
```